# Multiple select values to render static Block Content

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I've managed to render static blocks through a custom attribute on a per product basis, which is great, however it only seems to work with drop downs, I would like to use a multi select so i could allow the administrator to select multiple static blocks in one are, rather than have multiple drop down menus.

here's the code for the drop down

```
<?php 
$cmsstatic=$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attributename')->getFrontend()->getValue    ($_product);
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockID($cmsstatic)->tohtml();
?>
```

I managed to get the value of the attribute options out for a multi select:

```
 <?php   if($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('product_featured_attribute_3')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)): ?>
<ul><li><?php
    $_comma = ",";
    $_list = "</li><li>";
    echo str_replace($_comma,$_list,$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attributename')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product))    ?>    
</li></ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

but i'm having problems getting it to output the value as a static block. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

as i understood you want to echo all the block content which id's are defined in product attribute.

For that you can try this:

```
<?php
   $cmsstatic=$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attributename')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
   $blockids = explode(",", $cmsstatic);
   foreach($blockids as $kry=>$value)
   {
      echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockID($value)->tohtml();
   }
?>
```